# Social media authentication, keep authenticated between app and webserver

Tags: android, authentication, social-media

I've the following problem:
- We have a public app
- We have the option to upload images to a timeline in our app, but that upload is only available after logging in on social media (twitter, facebook etc.), by using Social Auth Android.
- That image is uploaded to our webserver, but on my webserver I still need to know which user is uploading that image and I need to know that he or she has been authenticated through the app.

How should I solve this?